# How to set .vimrc for c programs?

Tags: vim, macvim, tabstop

How should I set up my .vimrc so that macvim will set my tab to 4 spaces for c programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

`set cindent

set sw=4`

EDIT:
I did not read macvim in your question, so now it is like you can try above. This works in gvim for windows and vim in linux

Comment: It seems to be working in MacVim except sometimes it does want to revert back to the old setting.