# .vimrc for C developers

Tags: c, gcc, vim

There is a question [How to set .vimrc for c programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076074/how-to-set-vimrc-for-c-programs), but nothing especially interesting in there.

By what `.vimrc` options do you facilitate your `C` development in Linux? (e.g. for building, ctags, tabs...) Any ideas welcome, especially for "**external building with make**".

Comment: If you have make `.vimrc` on your own, you're ready to code `C` in vim.

Comment: Try to learn how to write vim script. The grammar is quite easy and learning progress will be very happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this?

https://mislav.net/2011/12/vim-revisited/

```
set nocompatible                " choose no compatibility with legacy vi
syntax enable
set encoding=utf-8
set showcmd                     " display incomplete commands
filetype plugin indent on       " load file type plugins + indentation

"" Whitespace
set nowrap                      " don't wrap lines
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2      " a tab is two spaces (or set this to 4)
set expandtab                   " use spaces, not tabs (optional)
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " backspace through everything in insert mode

"" Searching
set hlsearch                    " highlight matches
set incsearch                   " incremental searching
set ignorecase                  " searches are case insensitive...
set smartcase                   " ... unless they contain at least one capital letter
```

Comment: You might also want to `set autoindent` and `set cindent` to get automatic tabbing (or are those enabled with `filetype indent on`?)

Comment: I would recommend to use  `set expandtab`, `set shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4`  and not touch `tabstop` at all. `sts` will make the soft tabs behave nicely with backspace.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jslim89/dotfiles

This is my repo. Inside already got a few type of vim plugins including c.vim, ctags, autocomplete, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Along with options in plan9assembler's answer,

Run `make` from inside vim, you can just use `:make` but that won't automatically open the quickfix window with you're errors. To get that to happen, add a second `:Make` command [[1](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_open_the_quickfix_window_on_%3amake)]:

```
command! -nargs=* Make write | make! <args> | cwindow
```

Another thing I have is a recursive search for my ctags file. The following will use the tags file in the current directory, then search one directory above recursively till it finds a tag file [[2](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags#Configuring_Vim)]:

```
set tags=./tags;
```

Comment: I actually use `set tags=tags;/` in [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/m0tive/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc). I think it does the same thing...